# C# generic of generic type as parameter

Tags: c#

I want to make a class `class MyClass<TWrapper, TInner>` that can take two type parameters `TWrapper` and `TInner`, where

1. `TWrapper` is indexable,
2. `TWrapper` is a generic type `TWrapper<T>`

And I want to store TInner inside TWrapper. Using inheritance from IList, I managed to come this far:

```
public class MyClass<TWrapper, TInner> where TWrapper : IList<TInner> {
     TInner MyInner;
     TWrapper WrappedInners;

     public void MyMethod() {
          MyInner = WrappedInners[0];
     }
}
```

However, I would like to go a step further.

```
public class MyClass<TWrapper, TInner> where TWrapper : IList<TInner> {
     TInner MyInner;
     TWrapper WrappedInners;

     public void MyMethod<TypeInput>() {
         //do something//
     }

     public void MyOtherMethod() {
          //--WILL NOT COMPILE--//
          MyMethod<TWrapper<TInner>>();

          //while this works fine
          MyMethod<List<TInner>>();
          MyMethod<ImmutableArray<TInner>>();
     }
}
```

However, I get the error that "the type parameter 'TWrapper' cannot be used with type arguments", while using known types like `List<T>` and `ImmutableArray<T>` works fine. Is it at all possible to do the same without knowing TWrapper during code writing?

**EDIT:**
I have been asked in the comments what exactly I am trying to do, so here is the background to this question:

I have made a class that can store data of the same type in a N-Dimensional structure, where N is determined at runtime, without sacrificing type safety. To achieve this, I recursively call a method that adds a layer of `ImmutableArray<T>` to the structure, but I would like to expand this to be any "Storage Type (aka be a generic type accepting `TInner` and be indexable to return `TInner`)". This a simplification of the part of the code where I would like to write `TWrapper<TInner>>`:

```
public class NDStorage<TInner> {

     public void MyCallFunction(int dim) {
          //call function
          MyInnerFunction<TInner>(dim);
     }

     private void MyInnerFunction<LooperType>(int dim) {
          //print looper type
          Console.WriteLine(typeof(TInner));

          //Exit if final dimension reached
          if (dim < 1) {
               return;
          } else {
               //call self
               MyInnerFunction<ImmutableArray<LooperType>>(dim - 1);
          }
     }
}

NDStorage<int> myObject = new NDStorage();
myObject.MyCallMethod(4);
```

This results in the following messages:

```
int
ImmutableArray<int>
ImmutableArray<ImmutableArray<int>>
ImmutableArray<ImmutableArray<ImmutableArray<int>>>
ImmutableArray<ImmutableArray<ImmutableArray<ImmutableArray<int>>>>
```

which is desired. Now I want to be able to replace `ImmutableArray<>` with the type of `TWrapper`. Is that possible?

Comment: Because `TWrapper` is not generic itself.

Comment: if you restrict `TWrapper` to have `IList` implemented, then you could already use it as the type for the variable `IList<TInner>  WrappedInners;` this way you would not even need the second generic parameter. Or do you have any other specification that speak against it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to just have `public class MyClass<TInner> { public MyClass(IList<TInner> wrapper) { _wrapper = wrapper; }`?

Comment: Try `MyMethod<TWrapper>();`, although given that `MyMethod` is part of the same class, it seems a bit superfluous to redeclare the type parameter. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `MyMethod<TWrapper<TInner>>();` should be just `MyMethod<TWrapper>();`

Comment: I think this question would be improved if you could state what it is you are actually trying to accomplish. In some cases people go overboard with generics, using them where they are not needed, or expecting them to work more like c++ templates. But without more information it is difficult to tell if generics is an appropriate solution or not.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is _recursive generics_ or _variadic generics_, but C#'s  type system is not yet that expressive and so does not support either of those. That said, is it really _that_ much work to define the types by-hand or use code-gen?

Comment: The short answer is that C# can't do this; there are no "meta-generics" of any kind. Open generics are the closest thing that qualify, i.e. `ImmutableArray<>`, but they are extremely limited in that you can basically only use them for reflection purposes. If you really want this sort of flexibility married to type safety, you'd have more luck with a functional language like F# -- those languages typically also offer type inference that is far more powerful than what C#'s generics have out of the box, so that you can cut back a lot on redundant type declarations.